# Emoji android dont current display after save in data base

Tags: java, android, ios

I tried to save emoji in a mysql data base. In android it displays fine, but when I save emoji in the data base, I get "????". I know about the `commons-lang-2.5.jar` library, which I can use to encode and decode emoji with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(String text)` and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(String text)`.

But Android and iOS clients use the same server, and if I use `commons-lang-2.5.jar` on Android, then iOS will not be able to decode. On a related note, iOS saves and displays emoji just fine.

If Android and iOS are overwritten in online mode (across `socket.io`), the Android and iOS clients display emoji properly, but if I request history from the chat server, the emoji stored on the server will be displayed as `???`, like on Android.

**Update**

Simple example:

```
comment = etxtComment.getText().toString().trim();

new SubmitCommentsOnlyChat(comment).execute();

 class SubmitCommentsOnlyChat extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

          String message;

          SubmitCommentsOnlyChat(String message) {
              this.message = message;
          }
@Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "url");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

nameValuePairs
                            .add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                                    GlobalConfig.CHAT_ONLY_MESSAGE,
                                    message));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: @buhtz i update my qestion

Comment: Nice try for the first time. But please correct the indention of your code. It is unreadable.

Comment: I hope my edits make sense. Please feel free to revert or correct them if not.